# Best way to store attendance and get difference of time in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

I'm very new to the SQL language and MySQL.
I'm working on a little Time and Attendance application *IN PYTHON*. What it does is logs the clock in and out time. Then calculates the hours worked and returns the amount according to the time worked.

What I want to know is the best way to store these clock in and clock out times and how to get the time difference?

So far, I've made a table for the employees as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (employee_id INT(50) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
first_name VARCHAR(20), 
last_name VARCHAR(25), 
age INT(80), 
mobile_number VARCHAR(16), 
national_id VARCHAR(15), 
guardian_national_id VARCHAR(15), 
email_id VARCHAR(150), 
password VARCHAR(255), 
join_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Here the `join_date` is the creation of this employee and the rest I'm guessing is self explanatory.

I 2 things in mind. It was to either make two separate tables, one for clocking in and one for clocking out. Then getting calculating and returning the time worked in Python. For this, I don't know how to get the verify the employee_id in these tables. Do I use the `INNER JOIN` or the `FOREIGN KEY`.

or, I could have only one table that will have the clock in and clock out columns but I still don't know how to verify the employee_id.

I know that the `start_time` would be `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` but when I goto update the clock out time, wouldn't this be updated again?

I am lost. Please help me, this is very painful. I can't find my answers anywhere. 
Thanks,

Comment: You could have a second table with `employee_id, clock_in_time, clock_out_time` Then you can join your two tables on `employee_id`. You could also do something like `employee_id | action | timestamp` where action would be `"Clock In"` or `"Clock Out"` (for now) and then you only need to insert into the table when one of those actions happen. There's a few ways to build this schema.

Comment: I don't know jack. I wrote a very detailed question before but then my laptop powered off and all progress was lost. I am extremely frustrated. Please forgive me.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't make two separate tables (one for clocking in and one for out). One table for these events would make plenty of sense. Any way you cut it though, having `employee_id` as a column in this extra table is a must since that is part of your key.

Comment: @JNevill Thank you for your reply. Could you maybe describe in more detail as an answer? I'll accept it if it worked. Appreciate it :)

Comment: @JNevill I see. So use only one table. How would I set this table (CREATE TABLE)? And I don't know about "actions" is this a part of MySQL?

Comment: Don't store age (I mean, obviously!) and INT(80) isn't a thing. Other than that, crack on.

Comment: Thank you. But then what is the number after these data types for? I always thought it was the maximum number of data you can reach xDD

Comment: No; the manual explains it reasonably well. (Unsigned) INT has a range from 0 to 4294967295 (10 digits). Assigning a number in parentheses greater than '10' achieves precisely nothing. Assigning a number less than '10' allows numbers less than 10 digits in length to be 'zerofilled' up to that assigned value (I've not yet found a use for this). Incidentally, if INT(80) was a thing, its maximum value would be roughly equivalent to the number of atoms in the observable universe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way forward here is to create a separate table to store the start and finish times in. You can store them either as integers (and use Unix timestamps), or, better still, store them as MySQL datetime types - this way you can use function in MySQL, such as [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff).

```
CREATE TABLE shifts (
  employee_id INT(50),
  start datetime NOT NULL, 
  finish datetime NULL,
  duration int(11) GENERATED AS (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, end)) STORED NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(employee_id, start)
);
```

Then, link each row to the appropriate employee using a foreign key reference to the employee_id column on the employees table.

```
CREATE INDEX employee ON shifts(employee_id);

ALTER TABLE shifts
ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_employee_shifts(employee_id)
REFERENCES employees(employee_id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

> The above is probably pseudo code as I'm a beer into my evening :)

I've made the table a bit smarter by using a stored virtual column to hold the TIMESTAMPDIFF value. This way you won't need to pull data into your application to calculate the length of each session; let the database do the work! Just watch out for timezones...

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot. Like I said, I'm fairly new to SQL. Could you maybe tell me what `start datetime NOT NULL,` means? Like is "datetime" as data type? Shouldn't we use TIMESTAMP for this? And what does `STORED NULL` mean? And in the line `(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, end)` we haven't specified the end columns?. 
And other than that, ```ALTER TABLE shifts
ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_employee_shifts(employee_id)
REFERENCES employees(employee_id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```
All that just went over my head.

Comment: INT(50) isn't a thing either. In fact the number in parentheses after the INT declaration is (almost) entirely meaningless - but fair play as regards the beer.

Comment: "start datetime NOT NULL" is defining a column called 'start' which is of a 'datetime' type and cannot be null, i.e. empty. You could use timestamp, yes, but unless you need that level of precision, I'd stick with datetime. "STORED NULL" is actually two separate elements in the column definition: "STORED" tells MySQL to store the generated value in the virtual column "duration", otherwise it would recalculate the field each time you query the table. "NULL" is just saying that we expect this field to be empty, which is correct until you enter a value into "finish"...

Comment: ...The remaining SQL is telling the database that the data in the table called "shifts" is related to the "employees" table and is linked by the "employee_id" column.

Comment: @Strawberry You are quite correct about INT(50) not being a thing...I'm pretty sure MySQL turns that into a BIGINT behind the scenes.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much. Things now make a lot of sense (To me). What does this "end" in `MINUTE, start, end` do? I'm guessing this was supposed to be finish like `finish datetime NULL,`. Also, we havent defind "fk_employee..." so what does this mean? `fk_employee_shifts(employee_id)`. Other than that, we have now made a table. What would I use in the query to add to this table. `INSERT INTO shifts (start) VALUES (WHAT GOES IN THE VALUES)` and same thing for the finish?

I really respect and appreciate the time you haven't put in for me.

Comment: Yep, that should be finish and not end. You're defining fk_employee_shifts at that point (it's a foreign key, Google is your friend here). For the insert query, you need to insert the employee ID and start time, something like "insert into shifts(employee_id, start) values (1, '2019-01-01 09:00:00')". Then, when the shift is finished, either: "update shifts set finish = now() where employee_id = 1 and finish is null" (which sets the finish time to the timestamp on the SQL server) or "update shifts set finish = '2019-01-01 17:00:00' where employee_id = 1 and start = '2019-01-01 09:00:00'"

Comment: When I copy and paste your code, this line `PRIMARY KEY(employee_id, start)` returns an error.

Comment: Its a syntax error asking to check the SQL Version.
And, Why would I do ` "insert into shifts(employee_id, start) values (1, '2019-01-01 09:00:00')"` When I can do ' "insert into shifts(employee_id, start) values (1, now())"` I mean I am logging the time when the employee comes_in to work. What if he comes in late?

Comment: I was trying to demonstrate that you can either call now() or use an arbitrary timestamp that you have defined; use whichever is most appropriate for your scenario. The error might be due to start being a reserved word...try surrounding it with backticks (`start`) or name the start column something else, maybe shift_start?